# Making table data appear on hover (javascript/jQuery or css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have some span tags (icons) that are each in their own cells of a table element appear when you hover over the entire row

[Image when not hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPOjF.png)

[Image when hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9dK.png)

I am using CSS for this but am open to using JS as well

HTML

```
<div class="row1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
              </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><img id="preview1" src="images/dummyQueuePreview.png"></td>
        <td id="user1">Emma R.</td>
        <td id="fileName1">Ethanol v1.2</td>
        <td>Physical Science 1</td>
        <td>12/08/2105 - 13:46</td>
        <span class="optionTray">
            <td><span class="icon-bubble" style="font-size:30px;" id="bubble"></span></td>
            <td><span class="icon-stack" style="font-size:30px;"></span></td>
            <td><span class="icon-pencil" style="font-size:30px;"></span></td>
            <td><span class="icon-bin" style="font-size:30px;"></span></td>
            <td><span class="icon-checkbox-checked" style="font-size:30px;"></span></td>
        </span>
    </tr>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.optionTray{ display: none;}  .row1:hover .optionTray{display : block;}
```

It doesn't work

Comment: It is possible that they are visible but they are of width/height of 0. A way to test if they are showing/hiding appropriately is to put some test text into one of the spans and see if it appears and disappears as expected. If this turns out to work, then you will need to provide width and height variables for the icons.

Comment: I don't think it is valid html to have a `span` element as a child of a `tr` element. Try removing the span altogether and adding the `optionTray` class directly to the `td` elements you want to appear. You'll need to change the display property to `table-cell` instead of `block`.

Comment: It seems to work when I directly add the class to the tr or td elements instead of the span or the div elements that hold the tr and the td elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with css is like this

**Snippet below**

```css
#table .icon{
    width:50px;
  height:50px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
}
#table .row:hover .icon{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<table id='table'>
<tr class='row'>
  <td>Emma</td>
  <td>Ethanol</td>
  <td>Physical Science</td>
  <td>date</td>
  <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQyODNgIBQEVpEbju8f7473DbeKSSmCfjzzfrtRRykKzJXnQJsmOw' class='icon'></td>
  <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7j4zeqZB4theKrjb13e8XwhXXYpumwYEzTvhYclxrSrzS_5yJ' class='icon'></td>
    <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7j4zeqZB4theKrjb13e8XwhXXYpumwYEzTvhYclxrSrzS_5yJ' class='icon'></td>
</tr>
<tr class='row'>
  <td>Books</td>
  <td>Buildings</td>
  <td>Girls</td>
  <td>RUm</td>
  <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQZ0tgKhKWQ5bHf6Mvsz1FpLSxRLvSiQdHPtUIbOgi9UuQSfnobPg' class='icon'></td>
  <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaZN_Sne_mJmC3Ls8pgo0LF63aNKq5IfTZKyfqUvFLdyd3WvgKLw' class='icon'></td>
    <td><img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaZN_Sne_mJmC3Ls8pgo0LF63aNKq5IfTZKyfqUvFLdyd3WvgKLw' class='icon'></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this easily for multiple rows i.e. when you hover over row 3 its corresponding images/icons appear and when you hover over row 7 its corresponding images/icons appear

I presume this would be easier using Javascript?

Comment: javascript is powerful but css3 is so short to write for simple stuff...I can gave you a sample with js too but might take a some time with crunching the key strokes...:D

Comment: This works well!
Question for you - why don't all .items in both rows appear when you hover over any one .row?

Comment: after the :hover pseudo it will look for the child elements corresponding to that row where the mouse in and mouse out EVENT is triggered a/k hover.. every behaviour  is event based in the DOM which points to a target.

Comment: kindly tick answer as solved if it indeed solve your issue :D